# Saving text input from page view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

I have the following children of a **Page View Controller**:
[image]

My goal is to save the username input data once the done button is clicked at the last view controller. I have each of the view controllers with the same ViewController swift file. What is the best way to save the username data or gender data to a variable? I have tried saving it in `viewDidLoad`, `ViewWillDisappear` and `ViewWillAppear` but I keep getting a

> nil error

Any Ideas? Below is my code. Thanks

```
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var genderSeg: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var birthdatePicker: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var profileImg: UIImageView!



var downloadURL = ""
var bio = ""
var name = ""
var age = ""
var weight = ""
var username = ""
var gender = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



}

@IBAction func uploadProfileImg(_ sender: Any) {
    handleSelectLogo()
}

@IBAction func doneBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {


    let bio = ""
    let name = ""
    let age = ""
    let weight = ""
    self.username = usernameTF.text!

    self.gender = genderSeg.titleForSegment(at: genderSeg.selectedSegmentIndex)!

    if ((self.username.characters.count) > 0 && (downloadURL.characters.count) > 0) {
```

Comment: So I suppose you are trying to save this info for future needs in app and core data may be the best place to store the data and possibly add a Label that is hidden in the view that is set to the users input when a next button is pressed and then switch to the next page. That is my best guess not knowing exactly what is going on.

Comment: Pass All the data to LastViewController and save into UserDefault.

Answer (score 0):

One of the method is to save all the user input data in each page is by using UserDefaults and in the LastViewController you can access these saved user defaults

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(username, forKey: "Username")
UserDefaults.standard.set(gender, forKey: "Gender")
```

and so on and you can get/access these as below:

```
let username = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "UserName")
let gender = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Gender")
```